# get current user info using jquery ,REST and csom

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, rest, json

My goal is to get the login name and picture for the current user.
I am using SharePoint 2013 Foundation.
I tried three method and non of then worked correctly:

1. This is with jQuery SPServices:

   ```
   function getCurrentUserInfo() {
       var thisUsersValues = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
           fieldNames: ["ID", "Name", "Picture"],
           debug: false
       });

       var name = thisUsersValues["Name"];

       var ID = thisUsersValues["ID"];

       var SIPAddress = thisUsersValues["Picture"];

   }
   ```

But I am getting this error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'
>
> File: jquery.SPServices-2014.01.js, Line: 2414, Column: 17

2. REST API method:

   ```
   function getinfo(loginName) {
       var theData = {
           "propertiesForUser": {
               "__metadata": { "type": "SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser" },
               "accountName": loginName,
               "propertyNames": ["PreferredName", "PictureURL"]
           }
       };

       var requestHeaders = {
           "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
           "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
       };

       jQuery.ajax({
           url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertiesFor",
           type: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify(theData),
           contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
           headers: requestHeaders,
           success: function (data) {
               document.getElementById("profilelink").href = userProfileProperties[1];;
               document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = userProfileProperties[0];
               if (userProfileProperties[1] !== null) {
                   document.getElementById("Userprofileimage").src = userProfileProperties[1];
               }
           },
           error: function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
               console.log(jqxr.responseText);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Error:

> "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1,
>        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The method 
>        GetUserProfilePropertiesFor cannot be invoked as its parameter propertiesForUser is not supported.\"},\"innererror\":
>        {\"message\":\"The method GetUserProfilePropertiesFor cannot be invoked as its parameter propertiesForUser is not supported.\"
>        ,\"type\":\"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"stacktrace\":\"

3. With CSOM:

   ```
   //SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
   function getUserProperties(targetUser) {

       // get the target users domain name and account name.
       var tUser = targetUser.substring(7);
       // Get the current client context.
       var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       //Get PeopleManager Instance
       var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
       // Get the properties to retrieve
       var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName", "PictureURL"];
       var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
           clientContext,
           tUser,
           profilePropertyNames);
       // Get user profile properties for the target user
       userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
       // Load the UserProfilePropertiesForUser object.
       clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
       //Execute the Query
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
   }
   ```

I really don't understand where the issue is. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SP Foundation does not include the User Profile Service, as @Aveenav noted.  Therefore you probably do not have access to the REST endpoints for that service.  Instead you will have to use the user information list to get this information.  This will require two requets: one to get the current user's id, the second to get the user's info that you want.

First request:

```
/_api/Web/CurrentUser?$select=Id
```

Second request (Id will be the Id returned in first request):

```
/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items(Id)?$select=Name,Picture
```

My results: 
[image: REST results for second request]

**Edit**

Since you're doing this from an app, you might have to make some changes (not sure if the app web will contain the User Info List).  Change the urls to the following:

```
appwebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/CurrentUser?$select=Id&@target='" + encodeURIComponent(hostUrl) + "'"

appwebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items(Id)?$select=Name,Picture&@target='" + encodeURIComponent(hostUrl) + "'"
```

App will require appropriate permissions.

Comment: thank you all , i tried :/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items(Id)?$select=Name,Picture in the navigator and it works fine , but whenuse the ajax function i got this error : SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Comment: Where are you executing the code from? An app or a SharePoint page?

Comment: I execute the code from an app

Answer (score 7):

1) Get all properties of current user:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

2) Get single property of current user:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/PictureUrl
```

OR

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl
```

3) Get Multiple Properties for the current user:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl,AccountName
```

4) Get all properties of Specific User:

For Office 365/SharePoint Online:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|vardhaman@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com'
```

For SharePoint 2013 On-Premise:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\username'
```

5) Get Specific UserProfile Property of Specific User:

For Office 365/SharePoint Online:
`http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='LastName')?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|vardhaman@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com`'

For SharePoint 2013 On-Premise:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='LastName')?@v='domain\username'
```

http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

NOTE: I had issues with getting the specific property for a user on #5.
This worked fine though:

```
http://siteUrl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='cnmain\ben-phillips'&$select=DisplayName,AccountName,PictureUrl
```

Comment: <m:message xml:lang="en-US">
The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.
</m:message> i go this error

Comment: Try accessing the urls in your browser first when testing REST calls.

Comment: yes i test it all using rest client for mozilla : and i alyaws having error : at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.GetMyProperties() at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PeopleManagerServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, ClientValueCollection xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String ...

Comment: `http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager` and `http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager\GetMyProperties` return an error in IE?

Comment: yes mick , it return an error in IE , I use IE11,

Answer (score 1):

For REST api, you could use 'GetMyProperties'. Use '$select' to retrieve only specific properties. the ajax method should be 'GET'.
Here's a working example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +
         "_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=DisplayName, PictureUrl",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var result = data.d;
        var displayName = result.DisplayName;
        window.console && console.log(displayName);

        var picUrl = result.PictureUrl;
        window.console && console.log(picUrl);

    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried it and this is the error: responseText "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.\",\"type\":\"System.InvalidProgramException\",\"stacktrace\":\"  
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.GetMyProperties()\\r\\n  
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PeopleManagerServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName,

Comment: does SP 2013 Foundation has user profiles?