# How to get Active Directory data from SharePoint into android using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, active-directory, android

I'm new into SharePoint, i searched a lot for how to get Active Directory data into android using REST API, but i could not found any suitable solution up to that, for example i want to access logged user email id or user name into my autocomplete text view. any idea?

Comment: Why go through SharePoint for Active Directory data? SharePoint may not have all that AD has. Or are you referring to the user profile service? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @teylyn i want to get value form AD into json object form but i did not able to found any solution yes i already go through the docs but it seem its not accessible to out side. yes i'm want to AD using user profile service.

Comment: you sound a little bit breathless and pressed. Maybe you need to step back, calm down and explain what you want to achieve, regardless of tech like Android and SharePoint. Edit your question and provide some background. What are you trying to do? Big picture...

Comment: @teylyn  sure, i just want to retrieve the AD value and parse into spinner thats it, but some developers said its seem we cant access AD data.

Comment: Your question is still very vague. I have no idea what you want to achieve. What do you want to get from SharePoint? What "AD Value"? AD has dozens of fields for a user.

Comment: @teylyn i searched a lot about active directory value, the main issue is that i want  all user email into my text view using rest api, but i think its not possible out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Active Dirctory has rest API (you have one with Azure AD). But From what I understand you want to get the basic info about currently logged in user. Have a look at this answer should give you the right place to start.
[get current user info using jquery ,REST and csom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124909/get-current-user-info-using-jquery-rest-and-csom)

Comment: hi, i can not user Azure Ad for my project.

Answer (score 0):

While you are using SharePoint Online so yes you can by using [API Graph Azure Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, if you want to get all the users from the Azure AD, we can use [Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to achieve it.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

If you use SharePoint on-premise and use AD, we can create a custom REST API and use server code to get the AD users, then consume the REST API in your Android App.

Or we can synchronize the AD users to a SharePoint lists, then using the OOTB REST API to achieve it.

The following articles for your reference.

[**SharePoint 2013: Create a Custom WCF REST Service Hosted in SharePoint and Deployed in a WSP**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24194.sharepoint-2013-create-a-custom-wcf-rest-service-hosted-in-sharepoint-and-deployed-in-a-wsp.aspx)

[**How to Synchronize Active Directory Users to a SharePoint List**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1029168/How-to-Synchronize-Active-Directory-Users-to-a-Sha)